# How to add a background image in jetpack compose to a compose layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The following function is called from Navigation graph.

```
@Composable
fun InformationScreen(
) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = { /*...*/ },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 20.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Filled.Close,
                                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.close),
                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            content = { innerPadding ->//}
              
    }
```

Should I add a theme to this compose function? How to apply it and make sure the app these will not change? thx

Comment: I don't understand what you call Linear layout here. Specify what you want to do: add a picture to the whole topBar?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I've updated the question. The UI it's a simple layout with an X (close button) and a text in the middle of the screen:)

Answer (score 8):

You can add background image to a `Box` just by placing it under all other views. And `matchParentSize` modifier will stretch it to the parent size.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds, // or some other scale
        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
    )
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = { /*...*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Close,
                contentDescription = "stringResource(id = R.string.close)",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
            )
        }
    }
}
```